# how to create a own style for one tabBarItem?

Tags: gwt, view, tabpanel

i want to create my own  .gwt-TabBarItem-style for a specific tab in the tabPanel. But i don't know how there to set the style.

Does someone have a idea?

greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, where foo is the tab widget:

```
foo.setPrimaryStyleName("my-TabBarItem");
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.my-TabBarItem {

}
```

Comment: no, i want to change the style in the tabBar. Bot the style from the whole tab, greetz